# Django 2.0.8 crashes when resetting passwords are unequal

Tags: django

On one of web projects that use Django 2.0.8 I forgot the password for my account. So I decided to reset it using the "Forgotten password" wizard. After receiving the mail and opening the link, I got to the form where I need to insert my new password (field password1) and confirm it again (password2). As I made a mistake with writing two unequal passwords (password1=MyNewPass123), (password2=MyNewPass12), the app crashed with the error:

```
ValueError at /auth/password/reset/confirm/<CODE>/set-password/

Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 17. 

<PATH>\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in render, line 202
```

So I went back and tried again, this time using two equal (valid) passwords which were successful. I repeated the password-reset step, using a new password (again 2 unequal inputs) and yet, it crashed.

Searching for any bugs or related issued did not return any result.

What is the main question here: Why does ForNode render in defaulttags.py receive so many items, just because of two unequal values.. What could be the solution for this?

ForNode in defaulttags.py:

```
class ForNode(Node):
    child_nodelists = ('nodelist_loop', 'nodelist_empty')

    def __init__(self, loopvars, sequence, is_reversed, nodelist_loop, nodelist_empty=None):
        self.loopvars, self.sequence = loopvars, sequence
        self.is_reversed = is_reversed
        self.nodelist_loop = nodelist_loop
        if nodelist_empty is None:
            self.nodelist_empty = NodeList()
        else:
            self.nodelist_empty = nodelist_empty

    def __repr__(self):
        reversed_text = ' reversed' if self.is_reversed else ''
        return "<For Node: for %s in %s, tail_len: %d%s>" % \
            (', '.join(self.loopvars), self.sequence, len(self.nodelist_loop),
             reversed_text)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.nodelist_loop
        yield from self.nodelist_empty

    def render(self, context):
        if 'forloop' in context:
            parentloop = context['forloop']
        else:
            parentloop = {}
        with context.push():
            try:
                values = self.sequence.resolve(context, True)
            except VariableDoesNotExist:
                values = []
            if values is None:
                values = []
            if not hasattr(values, '__len__'):
                values = list(values)
            len_values = len(values)
            if len_values < 1:
                return self.nodelist_empty.render(context)
            nodelist = []
            if self.is_reversed:
                values = reversed(values)
            num_loopvars = len(self.loopvars)
            unpack = num_loopvars > 1
            # Create a forloop value in the context.  We'll update counters on each
            # iteration just below.
            loop_dict = context['forloop'] = {'parentloop': parentloop}
            for i, item in enumerate(values):
                # Shortcuts for current loop iteration number.
                loop_dict['counter0'] = i
                loop_dict['counter'] = i + 1
                # Reverse counter iteration numbers.
                loop_dict['revcounter'] = len_values - i
                loop_dict['revcounter0'] = len_values - i - 1
                # Boolean values designating first and last times through loop.
                loop_dict['first'] = (i == 0)
                loop_dict['last'] = (i == len_values - 1)

                pop_context = False
                if unpack:
                    # If there are multiple loop variables, unpack the item into
                    # them.
                    try:
                        len_item = len(item)
                    except TypeError:  # not an iterable
                        len_item = 1
                    # Check loop variable count before unpacking
                    if num_loopvars != len_item:
                        raise ValueError(
                            "Need {} values to unpack in for loop; got {}. "
                            .format(num_loopvars, len_item),
                        )
                    unpacked_vars = dict(zip(self.loopvars, item))
                    pop_context = True
                    context.update(unpacked_vars)
                else:
                    context[self.loopvars[0]] = item

                for node in self.nodelist_loop:
                    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

                if pop_context:
                    # Pop the loop variables pushed on to the context to avoid
                    # the context ending up in an inconsistent state when other
                    # tags (e.g., include and with) push data to context.
                    context.pop()
        return mark_safe(''.join(nodelist))
```

**password_reset_confirm.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block breadcrumb %}
{{ block.super }}
</h1>Password reset</h1>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% if validlink %}
    <form method="post">
    {% if form.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {% for key,value in form.error_messages %}
        {{ value }}<br />
        {% endfor %}
        {{ form.error_messages }}
    {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    {% else %}
      <p>Wrong activation code</p>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

**TRACEBACK**
Traceback:

File "\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  158.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = response.render()

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  98.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  98.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  314.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  314.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  202.                             .format(num_loopvars, len_item),

Exception Type: ValueError at /auth/password/reset/confirm/MzAz/set-password/
Exception Value: Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going step by step, I managed to find the issue and the solution.

The problem was in my **password_reset_confirm.html**

The code where the error was:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
# here it receives 17 values to unpack, but needs actually two (key, value)
    {% for key,value in form.**error_messages** %}
        {{ value }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
```

Solution..

After putting the "items" in the end of **form.error_messages**, I received a valid output with no errors.
Working code:

```
{% if form.errors %}
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
 {% for key, value in form.error_messages.items %}
     {{ value }}
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```